# Users: Reset all users passwords using batch or powershell?

Tags: batch, powershell, script, passwords, vbscript

I need to bulk reset passwords on a local machine (No network or domain just the machine) to a single password; such as %1Percent . I was wondering if this was at all possible with batch or power shell or some sort of script.

Answer (score 5):

With Powershell (Adminstrator privileges required):

- get new password from user input as a SecureString
- Get-Localuser enumerates all local users and pipes them to the
- where clause which checks against the users to exclude
- Remaining users are piped to Set-Localuser which sets the password entered in the first command.

---

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for all users" -AsSecureString 
$Exclude = "Administrator","Guest","DefaultAccount"
Get-LocalUser |
  Where {$Exclude -notcontains $_.Name} |
    Set-Localuser -Password $SecurePassword
```

Comment: Maybe it would be good if you could add explanations for your script ?

Answer (score 0):

Create text file with extension `cmd` such as `nuke_users_passwords.cmd`

with following content (substitute username and password as you need) and run it

```
@echo off
net user username1  new_password
net user username2  new_password
...
net user usernameN  new_password
```

Another solution is to use [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) to automatically enumerate local users and change their passwords.

Below is the VBS script with ability to exclude some of account(s) that need to be skipped. Save it as `FileName.vbs` and run it "as administrator"

```
On Error Resume Next 

strPasswd = "SuperPassword"
strComputer = "." 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = True") 

For Each objItem in colItems 
    Do While True
        if objItem.Name = "Guest" then Exit Do ' Skip some account
        if objItem.Name = "Administrator" then Exit Do ' Skip some account
        if objItem.PasswordChangeable = False then Exit Do ' 

        objItem.SetPassword strPasswd
        objItem.SetInfo 

        Exit Do
    Loop
Next 

Wscript.Echo "Done."
```

P.S. 
Run these scripts "as administrator"

Comment: I know this way but I am dealing with possibly hundreds of accounts. It would be better if I didnt have to do one at a time.

Comment: Oh, it make sense. I updated my answer, check it